# C# - Handle property that can be both single and array when XML deserializing

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have a XML that looks like this that I need to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Countries>
      <Country>
        <CountryCode>CN</CountryCode>
        <CurrentStatus>Active</CurrentStatus>
      </Country>
    </Countries>

    <Countries>
      <Country>
        <CountryCode>AU</CountryCode>
        <CurrentStatus>Cancelled</CurrentStatus>
      </Country>
      <Country>
        <CountryCode>CN</CountryCode>
        <CurrentStatus>Cancelled</CurrentStatus>
      </Country>
      <Country>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
        <CurrentStatus>Active</CurrentStatus>
      </Country>
    </Countries>

    <Countries xsi:nil="true" />
</Root>
```

My problem here is that Countries can have Country as single and array as you can see. To get it working I have it as `object` type now but it is hard to handle. What is the best solution to fix this? I'm converting it to `json` since all our other systems use that and this is the only file we have that is XML.

```
public class Country
{

    [JsonProperty("CountryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CurrentStatus")]
    public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}

public class CountryInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("Country")]
    public object Country { get; set; }

    //Does not work
    //[JsonProperty("Country")]
    //public IList<Country> Country { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("Countries")]
    public IList<CountryInfo> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleCountry
{
    [JsonProperty("Root")]
    public Root Root { get; set; }
}

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc);
var exampleCountries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleCountry>(json);
```

Update:

If I enable `public IList<Country> Country { get; set; }` I get the following error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[]' because the type requires a
>   JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: It's not because your array only contains one element that it can not be an array if it contains no element or only one.

Comment: Why doesn't `public IList<Country> Country { get; set; }` not work? How exactly does it not work?

Comment: @AshleyPillay I'm assuming what he meant that it doesn't always work as at time he could receive a single object (ie: public Country Country {get; set; }) -- not an array with a single object inside it.

Comment: `My problem here is that Countries can be both single and array as you can see.` Can you make it more explicit which is the single one? _I can't see a single one there._

Comment: @mjwills Check Country for Countries. As you can se there can be either a single item or several and this is causing a problem when deserializing.

Comment: @mjwills Absolutely but `DeserializeObject` throws the error that I printed with the example code above anyway. It does not understand that the single object should be an array.

Comment: @mjwills The problem I had was handling when a XML property can be either single or array. Have a look at the solution below and perhaps it will clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/3850405

```
public class CountryInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("Country")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<Country>))]
    public IList<Country> Country { get; set; }
}

public class SingleOrArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return token.ToObject<List<T>>();
        }
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol you beat me to it... I was referencing that exact post as I've seen it just recently